# How to get a text depending of a highlighted cell

Tags: excel

I have a big table and whenever a cell is highlighted in yellow, I want to be able to automatically get the text in A1 to appear in a new table.

Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmruR.jpg

I have no clue how to do since I'm kinda new to Excel...thanks all!

```
Entreprises Date de fin Monitoring 1    Monitoring 2    Monitoring 3    Monitoring 4    Monitoring 5    Monitoring 6
Inox2022-07-01  2020-01-31  2020-07-31  2021-01-31  2021-07-31  2022-01-31  2022-06-30
Solix   2022-06-26  2019-12-31  2020-06-30  2020-12-31  2021-06-30  2021-12-31  2022-05-31
Mécanique Inc   2022-05-28  2019-11-30  2020-05-31  2020-11-30  2021-05-31  2021-11-30  2022-04-30
Vidal 2022-05-11    2019-11-30  2020-05-31  2020-11-30  2021-05-31  2021-11-30  2022-04-30
```

This is the conditional formatting I'm using :

- highlight in red when less than today `=TODAY()`
- highlight in yellow when `=C2 < TODAY() + 45`

Comment: How is the cell highlighted, manually or from conditional formatting?

Comment: conditional formatting ! @BigBen

Comment: Should the values in the new table get overwritten or appended?

Comment: @BigBen I just want to be able to auto copy and paste a cell if the condition is met ... no modification or nothing, just a simple copy paste in a new table

Comment: Some sample data along with the condition used for the conditional formatting would be helpful in answering your question.

Comment: You can [edit] your question. It's hard to see additional detail in comments.

Comment: you can see the question now i think i fixed it the best i could @BigBen

Comment: @Ch Na If A1 is yellow, A2 is not yellow, A3 is yellow then should A3 be pasted into A2 or A3 in the new table?

Comment: A1 is never yellow. It's the name of the compagnies logged in A1. One compagnie could never have different yellow cells, only 1 cell can be yellowed per compagny. @Jenn

Comment: @Ch Na I will clarify my question, should the cell values for which the criteria has been met be pasted in the same table row location on the new table?  Meaning, should the new table consist only of values that meet the criteria, or should gaps be left where the criteria was not met?  
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrPYk.png

Comment: @Ch Na Okay never mind, I see your comment now, that you are looking to only copy/paste one cell, not a range of cells.

Comment: @Jenn Exactly like the table 2 in your image. But the problem is : I dont want the highlighted date to be pasted in the new table. I want the name of the compagny (that is not highlighted) to be pasted in the new table. Look at my edited question to see the photo.

Comment: @Ch Na You can do this with a formula or with macro.  What have tried already?

Comment: @Jenn I havnt tried anything cause I dont know any formula/macros, this is why im posting here...